# "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float' " in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to read a column in an Excel file, and write the data to a corresponding text file for the column in Python (with Openpyxl).
Some data are missing in the Excel file, like the 2nd column below:

"gappy.xlsx":

```
350.2856445313  -424.5273132324 -322.6161499023
609.8883056641                  -453.6102294922
780.6325683594                  -628.981628418
```

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('gappy.xlsx', data_only = True)
ws = wb.active
factor = 1.0

for i in range (1,4):
    with open('text'+str(i)+'.txt', "wt") as file_id:
        for j in range (1,ws.max_row+1):
            file_id.write("{:.3e}\n".format(ws.cell(row = j,column = i).value/factor))

#        I've also tried this, but I cannot write a file separately for each cloumn ... 
#        for column in ws.columns:
#            for cell in column:
#                print(cell.value)
#                file_id.write('%f\n' % (ws.columns[i][0].value))
```

Then, I got this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'

The reason is that the blanks in the the 2nd column are read as 'None'.
I know it's wrong to read the 2nd column up to 'max_row+1', but I don't know what else to do.
Please tell me how to fix this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can check that both arguments are not None before doing the division. And in case one is `None` handle it in whatever way you want.

Something like this

```
if ws.cell(row = j,column = i).value is not None and factor is not None:
    file_id.write("{:.3e}\n".format(ws.cell(row = j,column = i).value/factor))
else:
    # handle it in a different fashion
```

Comment: It works. I added file_id.write('None\n') under the else statement. Thank you so much!